# React Context API, Hook loading twice. Once without the data and once with the data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm building an internal react app with a flask backend that stores user details in the flask session.

My flask app uses the ADAL package to handle the Azure Active Directory user authentication.

To get the user details into my react app, I make fetch calls and can get the data no problems.

In my react app I'm trying to use Hooks, createContext, useContext, useState and UseState for the first time and for some reason the app looks like it loads my header hook twice. Once without the data and once with the data

[image]

I've created an example of my problem here https://codesandbox.io/s/new-react-context-api-ei92k it shows in the console.log the Header firing twice.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: To avoid this, your `App` should not render `AppSessionContext.Provider` until you have set the `user` in your state.

Comment: so is this possible with the way i've used useEffect?

Comment: I see you've figured it out. Pro tip: you don't need to assign the return value to a variable, you could just `if (!loaded) { return 'Loading' }` before your final `return`.

Comment: Thanks implemented, I still feel its rendering twice but maybe that's how its got to be

Comment: It will be render twice, which the natural effect of rendering immediately, and then rendering when the state is updated. Previous versions of React allowed for triggering the `loadUser` prior to the initial rendering, but that has been deprecated in favour of post-rendering effects.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem

```
const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    loadProfile().then(user => setUser(user));
  }, []);

  console.log(user); // you can log here
```

You are getting two time user object because in first render you do not have your user data and second time you are getting your user data from   `loadProfile()`.

Comment: let me know if you have any query